# How to iterate arrays nested in arrays

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array

I have the json array below and im trying to access the ProductResults bit.

I want the output to be somthing like this:

```
Term: 47, Type:HP, Payment: 229.4 
Term: 47, Type:PCP, Payment: 172.23 
Term: 60, Type:PCP, Payment: 186.82
```

But im struggeling to even access other parts of the array.

PHP:

```
$json = json_decode($resp, true);

foreach ($json['VehicleResults'] as $item)
{
    $data = $item['FinanceProductResults'];

    $v0 = $data['Term'];
    
    echo $v0;

}
```

JSON:

```
{
    "VehicleResults": [{
        "Id": "0",
        "FinanceProductResults": [{
            "Term": 47,
            "AnnualMileage": 6000,
            "Deposits": 1000,
            "ProductResults": [{
                "Key": "HP",
                "Payment": 229.4
            }, {
                "Key": "PCP",
                "Payment": 172.23
            }]
        }, {
            "Term": 60,
            "AnnualMileage": 6000,
            "Deposits": 1000,
            "ProductResults": [{
                "Key": "HP",
                "Payment": 186.82
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FinanceProductResults` is also an array so it needs to be accessed also as an array. Like you have accessed `VehicleResults` and same goes for `ProductResults`. So your code should look something like this.

```
$json = json_decode($resp, true);

foreach ($json['VehicleResults'] as $item)
{
    $dataItems = $item['FinanceProductResults'];

    foreach ($dataItems as $data) {
        $v0 = $data['Term'];
        
        foreach ($data['ProductResults'] as $productResult) {
            $type = $productResult['Key'];
            $payment = $productResult['Payment'];

            echo "Term: $v0, Type: $type, Payment: $payment";
        }
    }                    
}
```